SSLError: Max retries exceeded when using Google Earth Engine High Volume API
Every time I run this code using the xee package to grab data from Google Earth Engine and store it as an xarray Dataset, I get this error:
SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='earthengine-highvolume.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/projects/calfuels/image:computePixels (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, '[SSL: UNEXPECTED_EOF_WHILE_READING] EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1006)'))

Am I asking for too much data? I'm not sure what the issue could be. I'm providing my code below but you'll needed to change the CALIFORNIA variable to a different boundary because that asset is private if you want to run it yourself.
import ee
import xarray
import rioxarray

ee.Initialize(opt_url='https://earthengine-highvolume.googleapis.com')

def prep_sr_l8(image):
    # Develop masks for unwanted pixels (fill, cloud, cloud shadow).
    qa_mask = image.select('QA_PIXEL').bitwiseAnd(int('11111', 2)).eq(0)
    saturation_mask = image.select('QA_RADSAT').eq(0)

    # Apply the scaling factors to the appropriate bands.
    def get_factor_img(factor_names):
        factor_list = image.toDictionary().select(factor_names).values()
        return ee.Image.constant(factor_list)
    
    scale_img = get_factor_img([
        'REFLECTANCE_MULT_BAND_.|TEMPERATURE_MULT_BAND_ST_B10'])
    offset_img = get_factor_img([
        'REFLECTANCE_ADD_BAND_.|TEMPERATURE_ADD_BAND_ST_B10'])
    scaled = image.select('SR_B.|ST_B10').multiply(scale_img).add(offset_img)

    # Replace original bands with scaled bands and apply masks.
    return image.addBands(scaled, None, True)\
        .updateMask(qa_mask).updateMask(saturation_mask)

CALIFORNIA = ee.FeatureCollection("projects/calfuels/assets/Boundaries/California")

ic = (ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2').map(prep_sr_l8).filterBounds(CALIFORNIA.geometry())
      .filterDate('2019-01-01', '2019-12-31'))

ic_xr = xarray.open_dataset(ic, engine = "ee", crs='EPSG:3310', scale = 30, chunks="auto")

